# Why was I unable to rebuild jobs?

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins server which jenkins was upgraded from version 2.220 to 2.387.1, all plugins have been upgraded.

When I rebuilt jobs, it gave me these output:

```
Started by user abc
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DEF_GW_ENROLL_USER_PREPROD
[DEF_GW_ENROLL_USER_PREPROD] $ /bin/bash -x /tmp/jenkins81696621479514690.sh
+ export SSH_CONF=/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config/ssh_config_preprod-ue1
+ SSH_CONF=/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config/ssh_config_preprod-ue1
+ echo PREPROD
PREPROD
+ export targets=batch-host
+ targets=batch-host
+ for host in '$targets'
+ ssh -F /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config/ssh_config_preprod-ue1 batch-host 'sudo python add_user_pastdated.py web.pre.domain.com abc1234 1 target.internal.domain.com false AUTHSERVER_V1R1 KPREHA_002 8  PST true'
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...[WS-CLEANUP] Skipped based on build state FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've tried to do a manual ssh, by copying the config file from `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config/ssh_config_preprod-ue1` to `~/.ssh/`, and then run the ssh command, the connection was successfully made, I was able to enter the server.

The `jenkins.log` is empty, and the ssh plugins show no error message, so I have no clues at the moment.

What possibly could be the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Few test you can do: Check the file permission `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config/ssh_config_preprod-ue1` and the corresponding private keys, then the ownership, it must be owned by the Jenkins user , use `chown` if necessary

```
sudo chown jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config/ssh_config_preprod-ue1
sudo chown jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa (or the corresponding private key file)
```

Also check the ssh config `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config/ssh_config_preprod-ue1`

Try to establish an SSH connection manually as the Jenkins user

```
sudo su - jenkins
ssh -F /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config/ssh_config_preprod-ue1 batch-host
```

You can also look in the remote host logs `/var/log/auth.log` (or `/var/log/secure`